# querying VARCHAR2 with MAX in ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle, max

I have a column CLIENT_ID with datatype VARCHAR2
the data ranged from CL000001 to CL000163
so when i query the maximum value with,

```
select max(to_number(replace(client_id,'CL'))) from mst_client
```

I am onlly getting 163 as the max value,
I intend to get the CL000163 for the maximum value. What did i do wrong here ??

Comment: Well, the max number is 163... you called `to_number`.

Comment: I know the max is 163 but it is literally return 163. How to make it returning CL000163 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to change to to_number a direct max will give the output,

```
SCOTT@research 13-APR-15> select * from maxtest;

A
----------
CL000001
CL000002
CL000003
CL000004

SCOTT@research 13-APR-15> select max(a) from maxtest;

MAX(A)
----------
CL000004
```